# How to add parameters to telegram group invite link and get that parameters using telegram bot in group

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I am making a telegram bot using nodeJs for a telegram group management I need to give referral points to a user who invites more users using the invitation link so I was finding a solution to check the new user has joined using which link so I can add points to that user.